# Nuxt Seo and fetch method

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I'm using fetch() method for retieve the data from an api, for seo purposes i'm retrieving the same info with asyncData() for use it in the head method.

My question is, there is no way to access the fetch method state inside the head to wait the retrieve of the data and just use one way to retrieve my info so i can remove the asyncdata call?

something like this:

```js
head() {
  if (!this.$fetchState.pending) {
  return {
    title: `${this.post.data.attributes.title}`,
    meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: `${this.event.data.attributes.title} - Estudios Claw`,
          content: `${this.event.data.attributes.description}`,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
},
```

thanks

Comment: why don't you just use asyncdata and get everything there ? why do you need to use fetch ?

Comment: Hi Jimmar, I'm new to nuxt and the documentation i used recommends fetch, and i used mainly because when the data is fetching i load a spinner.

Comment: you don't need to use both, if you are just loading data then use asyncdata when possible (only possible on pages but not components).

Comment: Thanks Jimmar, so fetch only real diference it can be used in components?

Comment: has a little more differences, check out https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/ and https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/

Comment: Thanks Jimmar, will read it, another reason for fetch is makes more easy to acces other variables and objects ( like the locale or created variables in the .vue), I will have to adapt.

Comment: just keep in mind that `asyncData` is exactly what it's called "a function that will allow you to get data asynchronously" then it'll get merged with `data`. if you think about it that way you'll be fine using it, also you can access a lot of things like locale and store through the context passed to asyncData.